# Advancing one character past strrchr in C

Tags: c, string

I feel like this should be an easy thing to do but I keep getting segmentation fault errors. I'm trying to find the last occurrence of a character, '/' and then print one past that character.

This is mainly just for printing out a file, so that this:

`directory1/directory2/hello.txt`

should print out like this:

`hello.txt`

I'm trying to use strrchr to do this, but since it returns the last occurence of a character, It prints out this:

`/hello.txt`

I thought I could just advance the character pointer one past the slash, and then print that, but I get a segfault doing this:

```
void print_path(char *dir_name)
{
    char *c_ptr = strrchr(dir_name, '/');
    *c_ptr = *c_ptr + 1;
    printf("%s\n", c_ptr);
}
```

I also looked around and tried doing a method where I copy `c_ptr` to a temp variable, add one to the new temp string and then add a null character to the end, but that also caused a fault.

What should I do?

Comment: the code could use the function 'basename' to get a pointer to the file name portion of the overall string.

Comment: OT: Your nameing is quite misleading. The function implies a path is printed, but it actually prints file name. The argument implies a directory name, but it obviously is expected to get a full path passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do pointer arithmetic, this is wrong:

```
*c_ptr = *c_ptr + 1; // incorrect
```

it should be

```
c_ptr = c_ptr + 1;
```

or

```
c_ptr++;
```

or

```
c_ptr += 1;
```

in `*c_ptr = *c_ptr + 1` you are dereferencing the pointer and adding to the previous value at the begening of the string, a `1`.

After `strrchr` `c_ptr` will point to `'/'` character, i.e. `*c_ptr == '/'` so

*c_ptr = *c_ptr + 1;

is equivalent to

```
c_ptr[0] = c_ptr[0] + 1;
```

i.e.

```
c_ptr[0] = '/' + 1;
```

and after that, `c_ptr[0]` contains the character `'0'`, so the `printf()` must be printing `0hello.txt`

If the substring wasn't found in the source string, `strrchr()` will return `NULL`, so you should check for that too.

A fixed version of your program would be

```
void print_path(char *dir_name)
{
    char *c_ptr = strrchr(dir_name, '/');
    if (c_ptr != NULL)
    {
        c_ptr = c_ptr + 1;
        printf("%s\n", c_ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you should probably only do this if `c_ptr != NULL`, in case there wasn't a delimiter at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
*c_ptr = *c_ptr + 1;
```

You're dereferencing `c_ptr`.  That means you're getting the value of `'/' + 1`, whatever that might be.  You want this instead:

```
void print_path(char *dir_name)
{
    char *c_ptr = strrchr(dir_name, '/');
    c_ptr = c_ptr + 1;
    printf("%s\n", c_ptr);
}
```